# ASP.NET Calling WebMethod with jQuery AJAX “401 (Unauthorized)”

Tags: asp.net

in my local iis it is working fine but when i am hosting it on plesk it shows following error

401 (Unauthorized)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check the Authentication Settings on IIS. Probably locally you have set the Allow Anonymous authentication check while the same it is not set on the server.